# Fast but affordable way to crimp dupont connectors

Tags: connector, manufacturing, tools, equipment, crimp

I'm currently doing a small production run of a board I designed. It features a few pin header type dupont connectors which are used to attach cables to the board.

Now, I can surely crimp this using [a handheld crimp tool](https://www.tme.eu/en/details/ht-202b/crimping-tools-for-terminals/), but I could really use a faster and easier way to do this. I've seen a few of [these super-expensive crimper/stripper machines](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_v3iIYP2juQ), but as I said, they're super expensive. It's important to note, that I'm not going to open a factory which needs to do 100 000 crimps per day. Instead I need something that can help me crimp around 400 connectors in a single run without spending something like 5 hours doing crimps and pulling my hair out out of frustration.

If it were also possible to strip the wires during the same process, that'd be really amazing.

If anyone could suggest a method of crimping these connectors ideally priced under $1000, it would be really life saving. I don't really care whether it's a fully automatic machine or manually operated tool, as long as it can help me work faster, than if I'd used a hand tool.

Comment: Have you considered buying short lengths of wire with the terminals pre-crimped?

Comment: 400 crimps may give you a cramp or stronger hands.  But crimp displacement must be adequate and consistent to survive a 5 lb pull test.

Comment: How about to subcontract this job? You seem to value your time at $200/h, it is quite expensive for this kind of labor.

Comment: If you have no skill or experience or even a part number you better get the Mfg suggested tool

Comment: Efficient automated crimping is available as a service, if you can make drawings and specifications to support subcontracting this work out.

Comment: @brhans yes, but being able to crimp my own wires provied more flexibility. I could use it in future projects.

Comment: @AliChen the price I mentioned is the absolute maximum I'd pay for such tool. Also I would possibly use it a lot, also for other projects so $200/h is not really accurate

Comment: Also, do you people have any specific links for any companes priving such service? Ideally in the EU

Comment: 5 hours is 300 minutes .... 400 connectors will probably take longer to do

Comment: I think I can do them in about 40 seconds per crimp. if I had 400 to do I'd be looking for a way to make the crimper and the stripper foot-operated,  and possibly fix a guide pin behind the crimper to hold the connector.

Comment: Fast. Affordable. Reliable. Pick any two.

Comment: Damn! this one exceeds your budget by three bucks  https://www.aliexpress.com/item/220V-Automatic-Wire-Crimping-Machine-1-5T-Low-Noise-Terminal-Crimping-Machine-Brand-new-RH/32846514591.html?spm=2114.search0104.3.141.6077210eykuDmK&ws_ab_test=searchweb0_0,searchweb201602_5_10152_10065_10151_10344_10068_10342_10547_10343_10340_10059_10341_10548_10696_100031_10084_10083_10103_524_10618_10307_10624_10623_10622_10621_10620,searchweb201603_25,ppcSwitch_5&algo_expid=0a60c43f-99e2-4082-be84-f6ea1e9bbe48-23&algo_pvid=0a60c43f-99e2-4082-be84-f6ea1e9bbe48&priceBeautifyAB=0

Comment: I think I'm going to make my own machine

Comment: There are crimping tools that are motorized. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5te9OzDhyl4